# Is $E(\beta_{a,b})=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}P(\beta_{a,b}>k)$ true for any Probability Measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{(X_n,\mathcal{B}_n), n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a supermartingale, and $\beta_{a,b}$ the upcrossing number by this martingale in $[a,b]$.

In Resnick's Probability Path, page 373, in proof of proposition 10.8.4, he states $$E(\beta_{a,b})=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}P(\beta_{a,b}>k)$$

I understand that this is analogous to $E(\beta_{a,b})=\int_{[0,\infty[}P(\beta_{a,b}>k)dP$. However, to reach that equality, I need to assume that P is the lebesgue measure, or some measure which for $P(n,n+1]=1$.

Or is there a way to prove this equality for any type of measure?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: For any nonnegative integer r.v. $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

$E(X)=\int_{\Omega} XdP=\int_{\mathbb{N}}xdP_X=\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}}xP(X=x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any random variable $X$ taking values in the non-negative integers, we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>n).$$
This is a consequence of Tonelli's theorem:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\mathbb{E}[X]$$

Comment: Carmichael, thanks for your answer. So, this is only valid for $\sigma$-finite measure. I've added a small sequence of equalities, which hopefully are correct. Could please confirm them? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, your expression for $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks Carmichael